# How do I get the Oracle environment variable LONG?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find out the Oracle env var LONG (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG088).

I tried this:

```
select sys_context('USERENV', 'LONG') from dual;
```

It says the USERENV is not valid.

Without USERENV it says it is not enough info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`USERENV` namespace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SYS_CONTEXT.html#GUID-B9934A5D-D97B-4E51-B01B-80C76A5BD086) has a specific list of available parameters; you get "ORA-02003: invalid USERENV parameter" if you supply a parameter name it doesn't recognise.

The `LONG` you linked to is a SQL*Plus client setting, it isn't something you can query, and isn't really an environment variable - I suppose you could stretch to call it that; the documentation calls it a system variable which is perhaps also confusing. The database is not aware of client-specific settings though.

> **SET LONG {80 | n}**
>
> Sets maximum width (in bytes) for displaying ...
>
> To set the maximum number of bytes to fetch for displaying and copying LONG values ...

This controls how much memory and buffer space SQL*Plus allocates for retrieving LONG, CLOB, etc. values when it executes a query against the database, and it discards anything beyond that limit.

If you want to know the current client setting then from the client you can do:

```
show long
```

It wouldn't really be useful for you to know that as part of a query.